# PHP based tracking like Google Analytics

Tags: php

Is there such solution? All solutions seems to be JavaScript based. I would like to use a PHP server side code for page visits etc. Google Analytics is inaccurate - people block it all the time, slows down the page - I see less and less pros to use it if you have the ability to not use the stupid managers that demand GA to be on every page - so they can refine their "tactics" based on the GA results - which are screwed anyway ;)

Something that could work with a database like MongoDB or similar. I just want to count visits by IP address and what pages were hit, SO, browser,  etc.

I am not interested in the time spend on my webiste or their resolution. OS and browser would be nice, I guess this could be done via some standard PHP functions.

In the worst case scenario I would make this tracking program by myself - but if there is something already in the wild - it would be nice to know how others solved this issue and how to approach this without reinventing the wheel.

I need this kind of tracking for optimizing my website - e.g. if there is some attack - I can block the IP right in the beginning or IP ranges etc.

Comment: You can just create a little php functions which reads you database, check if an ip already exists and increment the value.

Comment: @HReynaud thanks, but the website will be big so I need a separate db just for this stuff - probably nosql will be more resources efficient than a relational db. I was jsut wondering if there is some project I can use or at least take an inspiration. Do you know about something like that.

Comment: Maybe something like Piwik (https://piwik.org/)? Or Googling on "php analytics with mongodb" gave https://github.com/Webiny/AnalyticsDb as the first result.